# 3D interpolation function

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, computer-science, interpolation

I've got a [3D figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WRGC.png) created using around 30k points and has different regions colored in an specific way according to some unrelated variables that come from a project I'm creating. Taking in consideration that I've got the exact values of each point in each region is there a way to interpolate the values into a function that creates an approximation of each space? like how Lagrange Interpolation does it but in 2D

I'm mostly looking for names of methods so I can try and implement them

Comment: [Crossposted to Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4403476/3d-interpolation-function) — generally the recommendation is to post one place or the other but not crosspost to both unless no answers are received after some time.

Comment: For any point $p$, find the closest four colored points $q,r,s,t$ such that $p$ is in their convex hull. Find $a,b,c,d$ with $a+b+c+d=1$ and $p=aq+br+cs+dt$; then let $color(p)=a\,color(q)+b\,color(r)+c \,color(s)+d \,color(t).$